# how to change xml data into table

Tags: asp.net

```
 <Report xsi:schemaLocation="Report1 http://localhost/ReportServer?%2FXmlToTableCardAd%2FReport1&rs%3ACommand=Render&rs%3AFormat=XML&rc%3ASchema=True"  Name="Report1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="Report1">

  <table1>
 <Detail_Collection>
  <Detail XmlMessage="<LogMessage ft="ACVS.Enterprise.Common.Journal.IntegrationActivityFormat">
 <StateCode>Admit</StateCode>
 <AdmitCode>Admit</AdmitCode>
<PrimaryObjectName t="0" o="0" co="0">tejapuriya, Rajeev</PrimaryObjectName>
<SecondaryObjectName t="0" o="1" co="0">Door3</SecondaryObjectName>
<_TO_ to="CardAdmittedFormatString_3" or="SoftwareHouse.NextGen.Common.LogMessageFormats.CardAdmitted">6</_TO_></LogMessage>" />
</Detail_Collection>
 </table1>
  </Report>
```

currently i tried one query in SQL server,but it is not working.

```
DECLARE @x xml
SELECT @x=P
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\Users\rtejapuriya\Desktop\Report1.xml',SINGLE_BLOB) AS demo(p)
DECLARE @hdoc int
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT,@x
SELECT *
FROM OPENXML (@hdoc,'/Report/table1/Detail_Collection/XmlMessage/LogMessage',2)
WITH(
  StateCode char(20),
 AdmitCode char(20)
)
```

this is my xml file .and i want to convert that data into table format.currently i am using the SQL server management studio.so can you tell me the query from which i convert the data into table format.

Comment: Table as in what? A HTML Table, DataTable, SQL Table? Okay your are currently using SSMS but for what? What you have tried so far?

Comment: i want the SQL table.and till now what i had tried is mention into the question

Comment: pass the xml values as sql command to a stored procedure and use that stored procedure to update your table

Comment: Their are lot of example in net. check this links http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Insert-Upload-XML-file-Data-into-SQL-Table-using-Stored-Procedure-in-ASPNet-using-C-VBNET.aspx, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30722/How-to-save-data-from-a-DataSet-into-a-T-SQL-table, http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8911c4/how-to-inserting-bulk-records-in-sql-server-using-xml-data-t/

Comment: actually i did it.you can see the store procedure  in question that i used.but it is not working.actually i am facing problem with tag hierarchy. so can you post the query.

Comment: can you tell me what query or store procedure, i have to write for my xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to just load XML document if you are talking about DataTable

```
           Dim dataSet As DataSet = New DataSet
           dataSet.ReadXml("File.xml")
```

Comment: can you tell me,where i have to write the following code

Comment: can you tell me what query or store procedure, i have to write for my xml file

Comment: ok that is code for vb.net in asp.net. You want to achieve this in store procedure?